# Convert the total amount in words

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, rtf, bi-publisher

I'm converting my total amount into words using bi publisher. Btw, the amount is base on the data from the data set. Can someone help me what to do? Thanks

```
<?xdofx:to_check_number,sum(COLUMN_NAME, ‘EUR’, ‘CASE_UPPER’, ‘DECIMAL_STYLE_WORDS’)?>
```

I expect the output to be in words but the actual ouput is blank.

Comment: What is the source system? E-Business Suite?

Comment: Yes. The source system is E-Business Suite.

Comment: The out of the box or “seeded” payments module uses bi publisher and the xml that’s generated for all payments already has amount in words. Are you not using the built in stuff?

Comment: @Lawrencxe I have provided another answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function xdoxslt:toCheckNumber

Like this:

```
<?xdoxslt:toCheckNumber($_XDOLOCALE, sum(COLUMN_NAME), ‘EUR’, ‘CASE_UPPER’, ‘DECIMAL_STYLE_WORDS’)?>
```

For a detailed explanation, check this [page](https://cleartext.blogspot.com/2019/03/bip-number-to-text-complex-version_30.html). But bear in mind, this is an undocumented function.

Answer (score 1):

In E-Business Suite r12, the XML file from the "out of the box" payments module has amount in text: OutboundPaymentInstruction/OutboundPayment/PaymentAmountText

Comment: I think @Lawrencxe is trying to print some subtotals in words, which is not in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

`<?xdofx:to_check_number(sum(COLUMN_NAME), 'EUR', 'CASE_UPPER', 'DECIMAL_STYLE_WORDS')?>`

*should work with fixed quotes and converted part `,sum(COLUMN_NAME,...` into`(sum(COLUMN_NAME),...`.*

Comment: I Tried this one but the output is also blank. Can you have another suggestion? Sorry, I was just a beginner here in BI-Publisher.

Comment: did you try without `sum` ?

Comment: I tried it and it convert into word. But I want is convert the result of the total amount in the column into word. Let's just say I have 3 numbers and I want to total that 3 numbers and convert it into word. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one which is working for my case.

```
<?xdoxslt:toWordsAmt(2300)?> 

CASE_INIT_CAP
```